# CSS margin issue - possible chrome bug?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I'm not sure if there is a bug in Chrome or if there is an issue with my CSS. What seems to be happening is that despite issuing a CSS declaration on .blockmenu li of margin: 2% !important chrome doesn't appear to be rendering the percentages correctly.

Here is the JS fiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/T3bWE/17/

The CSS is

```
.blockmenu ul {
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
}
.blockmenu li {
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 2% !important;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-position: inside;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    display: table;
}
.blockmenu li a {
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.blockmenu li:nth-child(3n-2) a {
    background: #e31937;
}
.blockmenu li:nth-child(3n-1) a {
    background: #002f5f;
}
.blockmenu li:nth-child(3n) a {
    background: #dcdcdd;
    color: #58595b;
}
```

The HTML is

```
<div class="blockmenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#!">item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#!">item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#!">item 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#!">item 4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#!">item 5item 5item 5<br>item 5item 5</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Is it Chrome or is it something I've missed in CSS, as it appears to render correctly in other browsers and when I bring up the development tools the left margin shows a reduction despite being a percentage - e.g. 5.641, 4.234, 2.828, 1.453 etc where as in firefox it remains consistent at 5.641

Here is a screen shot of Chrome;
[image: Chrome Rendering]

Here is a screen shot of Firefox; 
[image: FireFox Rendering]

Comment: You should not need `!important` for this.

Comment: It's part of a much bigger CSS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.blockmenu ul li {
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 2% !important;
    list-style: none;
    width: 25%;
    display: table-cell;
    float: left;
}
.blockmenu li a {
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

You had duplicate/incorrect display styles and you needed a width declared for the .blockmenu li a.

To verify that it works, I forked your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/f3sGr/